# .NET Core 3.1 convert to .NET 6 controller download method fails for no view

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

I converted a .NET Core 3.1 project to .NET 6 and now the download method produces this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'ExcelDownload' was not found. The following locations were searched:...

This is the method:

```
public IActionResult ExcelDownload(string TIDList)
{
    // ...
    // ...
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(stream);
        var content = stream.ToArray();
        return File(content, contentType, fileName);
    }
}
```

There has never been a view for this method and it worked with .NET Core 3.1. What's different with .NET 6 that causes this to look for a view?

Using the ClosedXML NuGet to create the Excel file.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you upload the minimal codes that could reproduce your error ? I tried as you've shown In my .net 6 project and it works well

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try FileContentResult

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> ExcelDownload(string TIDList)
    {

        var fileProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        if (!fileProvider.TryGetContentType($"{fileName.FileName}{fileName.Extension}", out string contentType))
        {
            contentType = fileName.Extension.RemoveDot();
        }
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            var content = stream.ToArray();
            return new FileContentResult(content, contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = fileName
            };
        }
   
    }
```

Comment: Although I'm rooting for you because I honestly have no clue about this, I fear your answer won't cut it.  You see, the `File()` method is just a wrapper to the `FileContentResult` constructor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).